# how to rotate a 3d point

Tags: rotation, rotational-matrices

this may be a silly question. but I just want to make sure.
Given a 3d point p (x,y,z), and the rotation matrix R. what is the coordinate of p after rotation R? is it R*P?
I did an experiment and found it does not give the results as I expected.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried post multiplying instead of pre multiplying?

Comment: It is. If it isn't - either matrix or multiplication is wrong.

Comment: Evan Knowles: post multiplying? you mean P*R? that can't even compile.

Comment: Pre or post are all the same. It depends only on how you threat vectors - as rows or as columns.